# Error with nested attributes Rails 5. can't write unknown attribute `address_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use accepts nested attributes on my model Patient. My Form I use `fields_for`, for join the fields of addresses with patients. But for my fields appear on my view on my controller Patients I have on def new this code for join the fields @patient.build_address, but this cause this error.

I am using Rails 5.2.4.1.

```
can't write unknown attribute `address_id` Extracted source (around line #18):


def new
  @patient = Patient.new
  @patient.build_address   
end
```

Comment: is belong_to, how to add this column ? I have a scaffold Patients and a model Address. I need update my model address ?

Comment: No, I have run the migration rails db:migrate. But nothing work.

Comment: Could you please spend a little more time showing your setup, rather than describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with the association is backwards. You want to put the foreign key on the addresses table.

```
rails g add_patient_to_addresses patient:references
rails db:migrate
```

And then setup the association like so:

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

Not only is this semantically correct (the address is a property of the user and not vice versa) but it also lets you change the association from one to one to one to many (if a user has different home and billing addresses for example) if needed.